# How to get Java to look at a specific location for a file

Tags: java

I'm creating a Jar file which automatically creates a target folder.

Within the the target folder I have an XSD file. When I execute the jar file via the command prompt - it is looking for the file in the target folder as opposed to the test-classes folder.

Is there anyway I can configure this so that the compiler looks at the test-classes folder for the file?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant java code and command line if it applies?

Answer (score 3):

The "test-classes folder" is just a random place on your hard disk.

Java supports 3 generic places to look for resources:

1. the *current working directory*. this is where your command prompt is.
2. the *user home* This is what you get when calling `System.getProperty("user.home")`. On Unix this resoves to `$HOME` and on Windows to `%USERPROFILE%`
3. the own *code location*. Resources in the same package as your class are accessed with `getClass().getResource("filenameWithoutPath")` But usually you place resources in a special folder in the application root and access it like this: `getClass().getResource("/relative/path/from/src/root/filenameWithoutPath")`

Comment: Is the leading slash for the last relative path correct?

Comment: @daniu: yes. Without it Java looks relative to the calling classes package downward.